# When accessing single element from list of float values, value gets rounded off

Tags: python, python-2.7

My list contains values which are converted to float :

```
time = [1472120400.107, 1472120399.999, 1472120399.334, 1472120397.633,
1472120397.261, 1472120394.328, 1472120393.762, 1472120393.737]
```

But when i do `time[0]`, the value gets rounded off to 2 decimal places like `1472120400.11` . How do I retain the original values (upto 3 decimal places for accurate calculations) when accessing single list values?

My code:

```
for line in line_collect :
    a = re.search(rx1,line) 
    time = a.group()
    newlst.append(float(time))
    print newlst
    print newlst[0]
```

Output:

> [1472120400.107, 1472120399.999, 1472120399.334, 1472120397.633,
>   1472120397.261, 1472120394.328, 1472120393.762, 1472120393.737]
>
> 1472120400.11

Comment: It looks like I can't reproduce the issue on my machine `>>> time[0]
>>>1472120400.107` ...

Comment: Works for me under Python 2.7.12 in an interactive shell on an Ubuntu machine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list itself doesn't have rounded values.  It is the default "print" that shows rounding:

```
>>> time = [1472120400.107, 1472120399.999, 1472120399.334, 1472120397.633,
1472120397.261, 1472120394.328, 1472120393.762, 1472120393.737]
>>> time[0]
1472120400.107
>>> print time[0]
1472120400.11
```

You can get full precision output by printing the [*repr*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#func-repr) instead:

```
>>> print repr(time[0])
1472120400.107
```